# How "factory" codes are used in proxy contracts?

Tags: solidity, proxy-contracts

What is this `factory_` exactly in the following piece of code?

```
constructor(DSProxyFactory factory_) public {
    factory = factory_;
}
```

https://gist.github.com/Sowmayjain/5ce5097d5a84f0cc1e1376d6918b25f0#file-proxyregistry-sol-L225

It should be something like uint/address/bytes etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's a `DSProxyFactory`, which is a contract, which is a subtype of `address`. So you can pass an `address` to that constructor, and the `address` you pass is expected to point to a smart contract that implements the public interface described in `DSProxyFactory`.

Comment: So just that particular `DSProxyFactory` contract needs to be deployed on blockchain (to get the address)?

Comment: Yes. (Adding more characters to pass the minimum required.)